# Have GNU make re-evaluate what is returned by $(shell ...)

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

here is a snippet from my makefile:

```
main_DEPS = $(TARGETS_$(d)/classes/player) $(TARGETS_$(d)/classes/monster)
```

It sets main_DEPS to the expanded versions of the other two variables.
This works as it should.

---

How can I replace:

```
$(TARGETS_$(d)/classes/player) $(TARGETS_$(d)/classes/monster)
```

with a program that gives the same output?

I tried:

```
main_DEPS = $(shell program)
```

but it appeared to set `main_DEPS` equal to the string value `$(TARGETS_$(d)/classes/player) $(TARGETS_$(d)/classes/monster)`, not the expanded versions.

I've also tried:

```
main_DEPS = $(eval $(shell program))  
main_DEPS = $(value $(shell program))  
main_DEPS = $(value $(eval $(shell program)))   
main_DEPS = $(eval $(value $(shell program)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
$(eval main_DEPS = $(shell program))
```

Here, the argument of `eval` (inner expression with `shell`) is expanded to get the statement to evaluate:

```
main_DEPS = $(TARGETS_$(d)/classes/player) $(TARGETS_$(d)/classes/monster)
```

If I properly understand, this should be exactly what you want.